# How can I filter a dataframe for rows between two given timestamps?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I have a large dataframe with many rows and columns, and I am trying to filter it for all the rows that have timestamps within a certain range - how can i do this?

My dataframe:

```
        timestamp          data     size     price 
   1690000000000000000      1       100       55
   170000000000000000      5       20        100
   1680000000000000000      5       55         44
   1620000000000000000      4        4         33
   1650000000000000000      10       4         1 
   1640000000000000000      15       2         99
```

I have made up the timestamps. And let's say I want all the rows of data between
`1640000000000000000` to `1680000000000000000`

i.e. I am trying to get the end result to look like:

```
        timestamp          data     size     price 
   1680000000000000000      5       55         44
   1650000000000000000      10       4         1 
   1640000000000000000      15       2         99
```

Comment: `df[df['timestamp'].between(start, end)]`

Comment: Thanks Chris, it's almost there, but the above gives me the data frame with lots of `False` values for the rows that aren't in that time range. 

Is it possible to filter just the rows that are in that time rangr?

Comment: `df[df['timestamp'].between(start, end)]` returns a filtered dataframe  while just doing `df['timestamp'].between(start, end)` will return a boolean vector . . . did you print it or assign it to another variable `print(df[df['timestamp'].between(start, end)])` or `new_df = df[df['timestamp'].between(start, end)]`? It is called [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df = df.loc[(df['timestamp'] > 1640000000000000000) & (df['timestamp'] < 1680000000000000000)]
```

If you want to include the numbers themselves, you can use >= and <= respectively.